# UWP Keyboard Accelerator FN issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts

```
<Button
    x:Name="PlayButton"
    Click="PlayButton_Click"
    Style="{StaticResource MediaControlButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
        <FontIcon
            x:Name="PlayButtonIcon"
            FontSize="30"
            Glyph="&#xE768;" />
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="F3" />
    </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
</Button>
```

I want to use F3 to play/pause the music in my UWP app. However, simply pressing F3 doesn't work on my Surface Book 2. I need to press both FN and F3 to make it work. What should I do so that I only need to press F3? The Microsoft builtin UWP app Groove Music plays and pauses functionally with pressing F3 only.

Another question is that how can I still use keyboard accelerator when the window of UWP app is minimized? The keyboard control of Groove still works with its window minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the behavior -- need to press FN or not,is related to the device that installed the app.When I run in PC,I only need to press F3,but it requires FN on the surface.If you still wants to change it,I have a workaround below,you can register Accelerator events on the page (e.g. MainPage).

```
public MainPage()
        {​
            this.InitializeComponent();​
            Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += AccelertorKeyActivedHandle;​
        }

private void AccelertorKeyActivedHandle(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
        {​
            if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))​
            { ​
                    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.F3)​
                    {​
                        // do something you want
​
                    }​
            }​
        }
```

When the window of UWP app is minimized,the current window has no focus, so the set shortcuts will not be responded.But the system has its default shortcuts(e.g. Fn + F11) can play or pause media.If you want to respond the system shortcuts,you need to allow backgroundMediaPlayback.You can try the [official demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback), which can also be controlled by the media button that comes with the keyboard.

**Update**:

According to the official sample,if you want to use MediaElement to play,you should set MediaPlay and MediaPlaybackList to bind the playback list.In this case, it seems can be controlled by the system default shortcut keys.What actually works is MediaPlayer.For more detailed information, you still need to read the official demo.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                            AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" ​ 
                            Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="100" Width="400">
```

Code-behind:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {​
            var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/xxx"));​
​
            // Create a configurable playback item backed by the media source​
            var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);​
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();​
            MediaPlaybackList lists = new MediaPlaybackList();​
            lists.Items.Add(playbackItem);​
            player.Source = lists;​
​
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry but adding that piece of code makes press either F3 or FN+F3 fail to work...I don't know why. I am actually trying to let default shortcuts to control my app. That's the reason why I am mimicking the behaviors of Groove.

Comment: It seems that `<Capabilities><uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback"/>  </Capabilities>` is almost the everything that I need to add. But adding that doesn't seem to work either for the background playing or background controlling.

Comment: I tested it on my surfacebook and it didn't matter. When you pressed the keyboard, did it trigger the event?Did you use the MediaPlayerElement to work for the background playing or controlling?

Comment: Do I have to use MediaPlayerElement? I used MediaElement because I want to customize it myself.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. I have manually implemented a lot functionalities for media element. It's pretty a pain in the ass to remove them...